# How to change Parse push notification icon in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my application i have used parse cloud code for sending push notifications to user.By default notification icon used app icon.but I want to change notification icon . I used this below code in manifest xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/noti_icon"/>
```

But the icon will not change. Any way to achieve this??

Comment: Please make sure your <meta-data> tag is inside <application> tag and noti_icon is in drawable.

Comment: i checked that. all are correct

Comment: @Surya the answer you marked as correct is no longer true as the API they're using is deprecated. The correct answer should be http://stackoverflow.com/a/30586391/1103584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `PushService`, each of the **`setDefaultPushCallback()`** and **`subscribe()`** methods allows an extra parameter to specify the icon:

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(context, SomeActivity.class, R.drawable.customIcon)

PushService.subscribe(context, "ChannelName", SomeActivity.class, R.drawable.customIcon)
```

Comment: @Surya:-Please let me knw if this answer is useful for you or not?

Comment: Both calls are deprecated

Comment: This is deprecated.  Edit your manifest file instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30586391/1103584

Answer (score 7):

The official way to change the Android push notification icon when receiving push notifications using Parse, as stated in the [Parse Android docs for push notifications](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) is as follows:

[image]

**IMPORTANT**
Make sure the image that you want to use follows the [Icon Reference Chart section for Notification icons](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/) - specifically:

> They should be flat (no gradients), white and face-on perspective

If your icon violates one of these requirements, your icon will show as a white box.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It always show a white box in my status bar.

Comment: @bagusflyer you must have missed that your icon is required to be flat with no gradients, which is why it shows as white.  Please read the full answer and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Write the line below to Manifest;

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/pushicon"/>
```

Please use 88X88 white image in 96X96 canvas.

Here is icon; It's white. (!)

[image]

Here is result

[image]

Comment: When I use this icon in my cordova project the aapt tool will remove the alpha channel before packaging the png. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score -1):

Or you could have just uploaded an Image on Parse.com under Settings and then Icon Image.