# Android 5.1 push notification icon is blank

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

When using Parse for push notifications our app always displayed the application's launcher icon.
In the latest Android 5.1 version, the icon appears to be blank (a white square).

I tried setting the icon in the meta data:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/noti_icon"/>
```

Based on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622844/how-to-change-parse-push-notification-icon-in-android)

But nothing seems to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Any solid pixel in the icon is painted over with white color on Lollipop. Use an icon with "holes" in it to express contrast.

Comment: if your icon is white, it get erased

Comment: follow this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop

Answer (score 12):

You must use a transparent and white icon under Android Lollipop 5.0 or greater. You can extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class and override the two methods to get your notification icon compatible with these Android APIs.

```
    @Override
protected int getSmallIconId(Context context, Intent intent) {
    return R.drawable.your_notifiation_icon;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap getLargeIcon(Context context, Intent intent) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_notifiation_icon);
}
```

Remember to customize your code to support Lollipop and previous APIs.

```
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_notifiation_icon_lollipop);
    }
    else{
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_notifiation_icon);
    }
```

Comment: I implemented the getSmallIconId and it worked as you exaplained

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Pelanes. So to extend it, basically you have to create a class like MyPushBroadcastReceiver extending ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and overriding getSmallIconId(...) and getLargeIcon(...). Not forget to specify your receiver in manifest. On lollipop both small and big icons will be used. On emulator 2.3.7 (which I tested) only small.

Answer (score 2):

It is not related to Parse or push nitification, but just how Android 5.0 handles notification icons.
See this releated question for details:
[Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Comment: It's true, but it applies just to notification bar icon - the icon on notification stays colorful.

Comment: When targeting the SDK to above 20 it will show white icons not only on the bar but also on the notifications

Answer (score 0):

Although @Pelanes has the correct answer (and should be accepted), here's what I did. Note that the [Parse docs for getSmallIconId](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.html#getSmallIconId(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) state the following:

`Retrieves the small icon to be used in a Notification. The default implementation uses the icon specified by com.parse.push.notification_icon meta-data in your AndroidManifest.xml with a fallback to the launcher icon for this package. To conform to Android style guides, it is highly recommended that developers specify an explicit push icon.`

So it is not entirely necessary to override the getSmallIconId() and getLargeIcon() methods.

What I did to solve the problem was I just made a copy of my icon, punched transparent "holes" into the icon, and set the `com.parse.push.notification_icon` meta-data in my manifest to point to this new icon.

For Android 5.0, it is required for your notification icon to be white and transparent, as others have mentioned. So creating the separate icon is necessary. One line in the manifest and one new drawable file is all it takes.

Comment: Are you sure that we don't need to define how different OS versions should handle the notification icon? I performed what you suggested and it seems that the notification icon set with `com.parse.push.notification_icon` is now used in both Android 4.4 and 5.1.

Comment: I tested with 5.1 and 4.4.2. 5.1 uses the new icon, 4.4.2 uses to normal app icon... Not sure why that is happening for me but not for you. Maybe to play it safe you'll need to differentiate though. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentText(data)
                .setContentTitle("Notification from Parse")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```