# Android Parse Push Notification Not Showing Icon in Marshmallow

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-notifications, android-icons

I am Using `Parse.com` in my app for Push Notifications.
But for some reasons the app icon in Push Notifications is not showing in Android Marshmallow 6.0.

I tested on all other version Below Marshmallow 6.0 and its working totally fine.

This Code is Also added in my Manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/push_icon" />
```

Please Help me With This.

Answer (score 3):

Could the icon file that you are using be the problem?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29898922/3017386.

Since Android 5, the notification icons are being masked. Everything that is not transparent is colored white. So all you are left with is transparency and white. A rectangular image might end up looking like a placeholder icon when it is really using your file but applying its filters.

Comment: yes I figured out my issue, Client wants the colored icon so I change my target api level to 19 and problem solved